# Qt: Action after QMediaPlayer stopped

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

I am trying to do some sort of operations/actions after a video of QMediaPlayer has ended. I know you can check the state of the player `player->state()`and that there is a state for "Stopped". But I would like to know how I can couple this state to a certain action, maybe by using a certain SIGNAL? Does anyone have experience doing this? or have an idea? I can't seem to find a solution to this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the following signal [`QMediaPlayer::stateChanged( QMediaPlayer::State )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#state-prop) ? When you receive this signal [`QMediaPlayer::StoppedState`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#State-enum) parameter the player stopped.